# Why does a different font appear on Greek and different on English?

Tags: fonts, babel, greek

I'm trying to create a pdf that contains both English and Greek. But the two different languages appear in different fonts. Can someone tell me why?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\newcommand{\lt}{\latintext} 
\newcommand{\gt}{\greektext}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\resetfont}{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{put}\normalfont}
\begin{center}
\resetfont
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{unipi_logo.jpg}\\
\Large 
ΔΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΗ ΓΝΩΣΗΣ \\[0.5in]

\Large ΕΡΕΥΝΩΝΤΑΣ ΤΟΝ ΡΟΛΟ ΤΩΝ ΔΙΑΡΘΡΩΤΙΚΩΝ ΚΕΝΩΝ ΣΤΗΝ ΜΑΘΗΣΗ: ΜΙΑ ΕΜΠΕΙΡΙΚΗ ΕΡΕΥΝΑ ΤΩΝ ΣΟΥΗΔΙΚΩΝ ΦΑΡΜΑΚΕΙΩΝ\\[0.5in] 

\lt
Fausto Di Vincenzo, Jens Hemphala, Mats Magnusson, Daniele Mascia 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: There is no Greek font corresponding to `put` (that is Utopia).

Comment: How can I find out what fonts can write both in English and Greek?

Comment: It depends on what TeX distribution you have. There are several good Greek fonts in a full distribution. By the way your `\resetfont` command is not what I'd use.

Comment: How can I see which one I have? (I'm a total beginner, I have no idea)

Comment: Just don't try changing fonts, then. Use the default and don't worry: that's the *last* of your problems. Think first to having the text in good shape.

Comment: incidentally, you load `babel` twice in your preamble.

Comment: Should I remove it?

Comment: You should remove the second one if you are planning to use both english and greek text. If you are only using greek, then remove the first one. In either case, there is no point of loading a package two times (and errors may appear).

Comment: Removed it. Did it affect my code in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use the (dubiously defined) command `\resetfont`, you get fonts compatible with each other:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large
ΔΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΗ ΓΝΩΣΗΣ \\[0.5in] % Why 0.5in?

ΕΡΕΥΝΩΝΤΑΣ ΤΟΝ ΡΟΛΟ ΤΩΝ ΔΙΑΡΘΡΩΤΙΚΩΝ ΚΕΝΩΝ ΣΤΗΝ ΜΑΘΗΣΗ:
ΜΙΑ ΕΜΠΕΙΡΙΚΗ ΕΡΕΥΝΑ ΤΩΝ ΣΟΥΗΔΙΚΩΝ ΦΑΡΜΑΚΕΙΩΝ\\[0.5in]

\textlatin{Fausto Di Vincenzo, Jens Hemphala, Mats Magnusson, Daniele Mascia}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

(I removed the logo that I don't have.)

[image]

If you add `\usepackage[default]{gfsbodoni}` you get the following

[image]

This is what you get with `\usepackage{gfsdidot}`:

[image]

Finally, here's a version that uses Baskervald and GFS Baskerville:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{gfsbaskerville}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{gfsbaskerville}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\Large
ΔΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΗ ΓΝΩΣΗΣ \\[0.5in] % Why 0.5in?

ΕΡΕΥΝΩΝΤΑΣ ΤΟΝ ΡΟΛΟ ΤΩΝ ΔΙΑΡΘΡΩΤΙΚΩΝ ΚΕΝΩΝ ΣΤΗΝ ΜΑΘΗΣΗ:
ΜΙΑ ΕΜΠΕΙΡΙΚΗ ΕΡΕΥΝΑ ΤΩΝ ΣΟΥΗΔΙΚΩΝ ΦΑΡΜΑΚΕΙΩΝ\\[0.5in]

\textlatin{Fausto Di Vincenzo, Jens Hemphala, Mats Magnusson, Daniele Mascia}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the GFS Baskerville font is slanted, so it may be not good as the main text font. Instead of `\usepackage{baskervald}` you can try `\usepackage{librebaskerville}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a [xelatex variant](http://www.eelvex.net/latex/greek-in-latex/) using the Linux Libertine/Biolinum fonts and a real title page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum}

\begin{document} 

\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{unipi_logo.jpg}}
\subject{\MakeUppercase{Διαχείριση Γνώσης}}
\title{\MakeUppercase{Ερευνωντασ τον ρολο των διαρθρωτικων κενων στην μαθηση}}
\subtitle{\MakeUppercase{Μια εμπειρικη ερευνα των Σουηδικων φαρμακειων}}
\author{Fausto Di Vincenzo \and Jens Hemphala \and Mats Magnusson \and Daniele Mascia}
\date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```